# Same query with different sorting is giving different results

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I have noticed that on OOTB SearchResults webpart when I change sorting i have different number of results. For example lets say that my search query is `contentclass:STS_Site path:"http://xxxx/yyy*"`, I'm using this JSON sorting string :

```
[{"name":"Last modified (Descending)","sorts":[{"p":"LastModifiedTime","d":1}]},{"name":"A-Z","sorts":[{"p":"Title","d":0}]},{"name":"Z-A","sorts":[{"p":"Title","d":1}]}]
```

and even if I set sorting on the same property but with different direction it gives me different results, like for example when i set sort 'A-Z' it gives me 6 results, when i switch to 'Z-A' it gives me 4 results. And when i sort on different proeprty, like LastModifiedTime it will give me different number of results as well.

Have you ever met with this strange behavior or am I missing something? 
Thanks and regards

EDIT: Oh and the behavior is the same using OM on server or REST.